# I can't make Gtk Picture Widget currect size

Tags: gtk, gtk4

[the picture widget fills a strange space][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hktgz.png

I've set both halign and valign for every widget to Gtk.Align.START, but while the label widget works okay, the picture widget still fills the window until there is no enough space.

So I put a frame out of the picture, but nothing changes.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? I have a little trouble understanding what the problem is... Also, please don't describe code put prepare a minimal and reproducible example and post it with the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.